# Run Script every 30 Seconds on Mac

Tags: macos, shell-script, cron

I have created a cronjob that runs every 60 seconds which is not frequent enough for me. It is a simple command: `wget localhost` How can I run this commenad every 30, 16 seconds on my mac?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run your command using [launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) instead. Use the property list files in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` and `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/` as inspiration. [Documentation on developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/search/index.php?q=launchd).

To specify a launch interval of e.g. 30 seconds, use the following:

```
<key>StartInterval</key>
<integer>30</integer>
```

Comment: A good tool for generating launchd.plist files is [Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/).

Comment: This answer got me curious about how the runtime of the program affects when it's launched, so I did some tests: as long the program takes less than 30 seconds to run, it will be started every 30 seconds (e.g. if it's started at 1:00:00 and runs until 1:00:17, the next run will start at 1:00:30 not 1:00:47).  OTOH if it takes over 30 seconds, the next run will wait until this run finishes (e.g. if it runs until 1:00:34, the next run starts at 1:00:34).

Comment: Thankyou for your investigation into that @GordonDavisson.  Do you know what happens if we are using ThrottleInterval and KeepAlive instead?

Comment: @openCivilisation I haven't specifically tested, but my understanding is that for a launchd item with `KeepAlive` true and `ThrottleInterval` set to 30 seconds (default is 10), if it starts at 1:00:00 and exits before 1:00:30 (i.e. runs less than 30 seconds) it'll be relaunched at 1:00:30. On the other hand, if it exits *after* 1:00:30 (i.e. runs for 30 seconds or more), it'll be relaunched immediately.

Answer (score 4):

You could try the following:

```
while true
do
<program>
sleep <time>
done
```

Replace  and  as appropriate.

Edit: When you're done needing  to run ever  seconds, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will kill it.

Comment: Assuming `<program>` takes longer than 0 seconds, this will be off a bit at first, accumulating offset time the longer it runs.

Comment: True. This is a direct opposite behavior to launchd, which will miss a run if the program runs longer than the time interim.

Comment: Your program misses these launches as well, as the program is still running. Only Doug's solution might get them, I don't know enough about `cron` to be sure though.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Mine will run, sleep for <time> and run again, regardless of how long it takes to run, unless the program backgrounds itself. launchd will run the program, and if it runs longer than <time> it will wait until it finishes. Cron (as far as I understand) will run the program every <time> (if <time> fits cron's granularity) and this may result in multiple instances running at once if it runs longer than <time>. So he's got 3 options for his desired behavior. Not knowing what the OP wants, I figured to post an alternative that may be simpler than cron or launchd.

Answer (score 0):

Write a bash script which runs every minute. Put the wget in a loop, or simply consecutive calls, with `sleep 30` between each call.